# Can I mod binoculars to connect a T2 adapter (for EOS)?

Tags: zoom

I'm afraid of breaking my binoculars if I remove the eyepiece. I'm looking for a cheap way to get some zoom for a lower price than a celestial telescope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here are some adapters](http://www.optics4birding.com/slr-camera-adapters.html) for all types of optics to SLR bodies and [this thread](http://stargazerslounge.com/topic/96924-attaching-a-cam-to-binoculars/) offers some suggestions on how to do it. For what its worth you may be able to get them to all screw together but you may have focusing issues. It will really depend on the binoculars you have and the adapters you can find (or make if you are crafty). On one hand you may be able to mount them right to the body if you can get all the focal planes to line up. On the other hand you may have success mounting them in front of the existing lens you have.

Comment: I tried using two tripods with binauculars on one and camera on the other, kinda works but is a real hassle to change positions and keep a straight line of sight through all that.

Comment: You may want to try using a single tripod and some kind of bar system to mount them on the same plane. It really all depends how much you want to spend. At some point the adapters, mounts, brackets and what not may be more expensive then just a new lens.